# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. Error in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fatal-error, web-development-server

When I am writing the php artisan migrate command then I have see something like this:-

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = crudtwo and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

  1   C:\Users\NaimBiswas\Desktop\Laravel\four\crudtwo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ")

  2   C:\Users\NaimBiswas\Desktop\Laravel\four\crudtwo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=crudtwo", "root", "", [])
```

**After few hour I have find a solution. The solution is just remove DB_HOST=mysql from the .env file
Now my question is can anyone explain more about this, and why this error came, and why it's solve after remove DB_HOST=mysql.**

Comment: `DB_HOST` is where your mysql server resides, not the type of server it is. It will most likely be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` for a dev server

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5483

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=crudtwo", "root", "", [])` shows that you have a wrong entry in .env file

Change the DB_HOST in `.env` file as

```
//Change
DB_HOST=mysql

//To
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```